# Centering caption table title into the two column article style (stylish article template)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, two-column

I created a width table from the modified template link (source: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/stylish-article-template/grgwqvchdmns), which I put in the script. However, I haven't been able to moved the table title to the top center, as seen in the figure. What should I do?

[image: Centering caption table title]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Stylish Article
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (13/4/14)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{SelfArx} % Document font size and equations flushed left
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\selectbiblanguage{bahasa}
\addto{\captionsbahasa}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Required to insert dummy text. To be removed otherwise
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{30pt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLUMNS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.55cm} % Distance between the two columns of text
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.75pt} % Width of the border around the abstract

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COLORS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{0,0,90} % Color of the article title and sections
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,20,20} % Color of the boxes behind the abstract and headings

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for hyperlinks

\hypersetup{
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks,
    breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=color2,
    citecolor=color1,
    linkcolor=color1,
    bookmarksopen=false,
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfauthor={Author},
    urlfont={arial}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \setcounter{figure}{0}
  \setcounter{table}{0}
  \renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}
  \renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}\arabic{figure}}
  \renewcommand\thetable{\Alph{section}\arabic{table}}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Output the title and abstract box
\tableofcontents % Output the contents section
\thispagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering from the first page
%start encoding to unicode
%Note that your layout must support arabic text when compiling
\setcode{utf8}
%To start typing in Arabic use the command arabtext

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ARTICLE CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Introduction} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering
\parindent

The Arabic text \RL{اللغة العربية} states the important thing. \lipsum[1]

Anyone can learn Arabic \RL{اللغة العربية} relatively easily. \lipsum[2]


\begin{strip}
Furthermore, the Arabic text \RL{اللغة العربية}  states the more important thing.   Sed commodo posuere pede. Ut quis purus. Sed ac odio. Sed vehicula hendrerit sem. Duis non odio. Morbiut dui. Sed accumsan risus eget odio. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. 
\end{strip}

\begin{center}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Numbers} 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{rcccccccccc}
\hline

    & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J\\ 
\hline
1 & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 \\ 
2 & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 \\ 
3 & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789   & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 & 0123456789 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}}
\noalign{\vskip 0.1cm}
\footnotesize
Source: Central Bureau of Statistics
\noalign{\vskip 1cm}
\end{table} 
\end{center}

\begin{strip}
The table above contains the most important information in Arabic  \RL{اللغة العربية}  numerals. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec odio elit, dictum in, hendrerit sit amet, egestas sed leo.
\end{strip}
    
%------------------------------------------------

\section{Method}
\lipsum[5]

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Results and Discussion}


\lipsum[7]


 %------------------------------------------------

\section{Conclusion}

\lipsum[8]

%------------------------------------------------
\phantomsection
\section{Acknowledgment} 

\lipsum[9]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%   REFERENCE LIST
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{babalpha}
\bibliography{sample}
\newpage
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{onecolumn}
\section*{Appendix} % The \section*{} command stops section numbering
\end{onecolumn}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix} % Adds this section to the table of contents

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use either the `table*` environment  or the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`stttools` bundle) to nest the `table` environment. Also, don't use the `center` environment, as it adds spurious vertical spacing to the normal spacing of `table` – use the `\centering` command instead. Last point: never use `\resizebox`  with tables: you'll obtain inconsistent font sizes. If the table overflows into the margin, use a smaller font size and/or reduce the intercolumn spacing, which is set by the value of `\tabcolsep` (6pt by default, which makes 12pt between their contents)

Comment: Another trick is to use \twocolumn[\tableofconternts].  This can only be done once per page, however, and is probably already being used for the title.